# Trying to run GraphQL in asp .net 7 app always crashes

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, graphql, asp.net-core-7.0

So I would like to get my GraphQL app running on an asp .net core 7 app, but the program always crashes. I cant seem figure out what is wrong with this. Not even the event viewer tells any useful messages. The bare minimum code for the setup is as follows with HotChocolate as the chosen library.

```
using RSODiscussionMicroServiceAPI.GraphQL;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args); builder.Services.AddGraphQLServer().AddQueryType(q => q.Name("Query")).AddType<DiscussionQueryResolver>();

// Database connection works without problems

builder.Services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(); builder.Services.AddScoped<IDiscussionRepository, DiscussionRepository>(); //In each microservice a different repository/serice is inlcuded. If more tables are needed add more repos related to the microservice.

builder.Services.AddScoped<IDiscussionLogic, DiscussionLogic>();

//In each microservice a different repository/serice is inlcuded.*/ // Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

// APP.

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGraphQL();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();
```

and the DiscussionResolver.cs class

```
namespace RSODiscussionMicroServiceAPI.GraphQL;

[ExtendObjectType("Query")]

public class DiscussionQueryResolver {

public async Task<Discussion> GetDiscussionAsync(int id, IDiscussionLogic discussionLogic) => await discussionLogic.GetDiscussionAsync(id);

}
```

I am using the unit of work-repository pattern. A business logic class is between the two and simply don't know how to run the app let alone, make queries and insert new data to the database. The current version of the app is available [here](https://github.com/Dezuranje-si/rso-discussions-service/tree/develop).

Comment: First of all `always crashes` isn't an error message. Post the full exception text. Not just the title or message but the *full* exception text returned by `Exception.ToString()`. The phrase `using the unit of work-repository pattern` doesn't explain anything. We can't guess what your code does, whether it throws any exceptions, uses connections properly etc

Comment: If you use EF Core, then the "repository" code is *causing* problems. A DbContext is already a multi-entity repository and Unit-of-Work. It's neither a database connection nor a database model. EF is an ORM and like all ORMs it tries to give the impression of working with in-memory objects, not tables and rows

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I do not get any specific errors or exeptions. If I got them, I would have listed them here.

Comment: What does `crashes` mean then? Anyway, the code is full of the bugs common with all such non-repository implementations. The "unit of work" isn't, and tries to dispose a DbContext that may already be disposed. `InsertAsync` doesn't insert anything and may not even connect to the database. As I said, DbContext is a Unit-of-Work already and all pending changes will be stored *only* when `SaveChanges` is called. `AddAsync` is a specialized method *only* meant for custom key generation strategies like hi-lo

Comment: When I start this VS tells me, "Unable to connect web server 'https'. The web server is no longer runnning. No other errors are present. I am using this tutorial as a point of reference. https://www.ezzylearning.net/tutorial/building-graphql-apis-in-asp-net-core